# Using RSA encryption in Java without BouncyCastle

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

In my program, I'm trying to encrypt some plaintext with RSA using the following code:

```
static String RSAEncrypt(String pubkey, String plain){
    return encrypt(pubkey,plain,"RSA");
}
static String encrypt(String stringKey, String plain, String algo){
    String enc="failed";
    try{
    byte[] byteKey  = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(stringKey);
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey,algo);

    byte[] data = plain.getBytes();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algo);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data);
    enc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    return enc;
}
```

However, when it runs, it shows the following error:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:877)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1212)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1152)
at Crypto.encrypt(Crypto.java:37)
at Crypto.RSAEncrypt(Crypto.java:62)
```

I have tried changing it to RSA/None/PKCS1Padding and RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding to no avail.. I know that installing BouncyCastle may help but I'd like to avoid it (I'd like to avoid more dependencies and I've been having some issues installing it anyway). Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: You need an RSA **PublicKey** during init. Not a symmetric **SecretKey**.

Comment: How can I generate an RSAPublicKey with a byte[] key instead of BigInts?

Comment: Well you *could* pass a byte array into the constructor of BigInteger. But the fact that you're asking how to do so suggests you're doing something wrong. RSA keys, in order to be secure, can't just be formed out of any old string of bytes. They have to comply with certain conditions. That's why the call KeyPairGenerator.genKeyPair() is provided for you.

Comment: I don't know if this tutorial of mine on RSA encryption is of any help http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml

Comment: The byte[] array was created with a key generator and then used .getEncoded() on the keys to get them. So, the solution was just:
      PublicKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new     X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey));
Sorry for the hassle, hope this helps someone who makes the same mistake I did..

Comment: Actually, that still doesn't work... Now i have " RSAPrivateKey key = (RSAPrivateKey)KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(byteKey));" but it still throws "No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was said in the comments, `SecretKeySpec` is for symmetric algorithms only. You mentioned that you got your `byte[]` containing the key by calling `getEncoded`.

There are two possibilities and two resulting formats:

#### Encoding of an RSA PrivateKey

Calling `PrivateKey#getEncoded` on an instance of an RSA private key will result in a PKCS#8 encoding for private keys, and it can be restored with the help of [PKCS8EncodedKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html).

#### Encoding of an RSA PublicKey

`PublicKey#getEncoded` on an RSA public key results in the generic X.509 public key encoding, and can be restored with [X509EncodedKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html).

#### Example Usage

```
byte[] data = "test".getBytes("UTF8");
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(512);
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();
        
byte[] pk = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pk);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
        
byte[] priv = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec2 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(priv);
PrivateKey privKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec2);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
byte[] plain = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        
System.out.println(new String(plain, "UTF8")); //=> "test"
```